# Internationalisation of bash scripts

Tags: bash, internationalization

I want to get the language locale so that I can call the relevant help function for the specific language.  I can use `locale` to get the `LANG` or `LANGUAGE` variable.
But need some assistance to implement the check with a conditional for a specific language.

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What kind of check? What specific language? Should many or all possible languages branch off to their own help functions? I guess you need either a `case` statement of `if` statement.

Comment: For now I will have help functions in english, french and italian: `help_en`, `help_fr`, `help_it`.  Could simply do `comlang="$LANG"`.  Would need to match `en`, `fr`, `it` in `comlang` with `case` then.

Comment: I think it closed prematurely.

Comment: It is something that happens quite often.  The curse of moderation and the eagerness to interfere !

Comment: Related: [How to add localization support](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098) or you may use `gettext`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following script could be part of your bash shellscript.

```
#!/bin/bash

function help_fr () {
    echo "Francais"
}
#
function help_it () {
    echo "Italiano"
}
#
function help_en () {
    echo "English"
}

# main

curlang="${LANG:0:2}"

case "$curlang" in
 fr)
  help_fr
  ;;
 it)
  help_it
  ;;
 *) # assuming default English
  help_en
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Many Thanks @sudodus

Comment: @Fatipati, I'm glad I could help you. You are welcome :-)